# Which tool or view is used to create this layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-view, android-calendar

[image: This is calendar layout]

The blue rectangle in which test is written, how it is covering ,one full and some portion of lower and upper cell?, ,,, how these cells are made? , this isnt a simple grid. consider this ,what this layout contains, how blue rectangle can cover a specified area.?
help out

Answer (score 2):

This is probably a custom view.

The background texture is a Bitmap , the cells are line drawn on a canvas and the blue area with text is a drawn rectangle.

When you create the view , you know oh many pixel represent an hour , so you should be able to give an exact position to the rectangle.

At least it's how i would do it.

You should have look at [Creating Custom Views](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html) in android resources and more specificaly read [Custom Drawing](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/custom-drawing.html)

Comment: yah that can be the only possibility one can achieve such layout, i will start working on your idea ,thanx

Comment: The Image is having vertical scroll , how can we give vertical scroll to a canvas?

Answer (score 0):

To create such view you can:

1. create your custom view and draw on its canvas
2. use [GridLayout](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/11/new-layout-widgets-space-and-gridlayout.html) that's available as a support library for android 2.1

I suggest to use the second variant.